# How to wrap multiple Angular Modules under one injected Module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an Angular project that will require modularisation and I will be creating many small modules for it. Example: `myApp.core`, `myApp.components.component1` `myApp.components.component2` etc. each being its own file compiled into one with gulp. When I inject `myApp` into another project, I want to be able to consume all modules in one `myApp` injection, like so:

```js
angular.module('project2', ['myApp'])
```

instead of:

```js
angular.module('project2', [
    'myApp.core', 
    'myApp.components.component1', 
    'myApp.components.component2'
])
```

Much like the Angular team have done with Material. Everything is its own module, but in order to use Angular Material, you only have to add `ngMaterial` as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  angular.module('project2', ['myApp']);

  angular.module('myApp', ['components']);

  angular.module('components', ['component1','component2','component3']);

  angular.module('component1', []);
  angular.module('component2', []);
  angular.module('component3', []);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I wasn't setting the components as actual dependencies of the top-level module.